# React.js Passport Authentication unable to get req.user from client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate a user through some API configured with passportjs. When I run the authentication request I get the redirect to the success route, but I can't get req.user. I tried through Postman and it works. I don't know what I'm forgetting. Could anyone help me?

This is my success route:

```
app.get("/success", async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user){
        return res.status(200).json({
            user: req.user,
            message: "Logged"
        });
    }
    else {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: "User authentication failed"
        });
    }
});
```

This is my react code:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3001/login", {
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            redirect: "follow",
            body: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password})
        }).then(resp => {
            return resp.json();
        }).then(data => console.log(data))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are calling the `success/` route you need to add the `authorization` header along with the fetch request. We need to add the Basic jwt | authentication token as the authorization key

```
const response = await fetch(apiURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 
            // add the basic jwt | drf token for Authorization Key
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(yourNewData)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually, I just noticed that I forgot _credential: "include"_ in fetch request... Adding `app.use(cors({
 credentials: true,
 origin: "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
}));` I can get the correct response, is this enough ? Or can this cors configuration bring other problems ?

Comment: Did you able to get `re.user`??

Comment: Yes.. I got the correct response to set the user

Comment: Then thats fine, the only thing with the cors is if you need to access the endpoint from other instance then you just need to add the instance url in the cors origin array